# Versioning Embedded Software

Tags: embedded, versioning, msp430

I'm working on MSP430 Launchpad and writing some simple softwares on this launchpad. I'm changing my software by adding new features and upload the new software to the launchpad. After some time i forget which version was on the launchpad. I want to know how can i learn which software version was on the launchpad. What is the best way to learn which software is on the launchpad?

Comment: Implement something which spits out the software version on your favourite serial bus?

Comment: you can have your make/build system generate a header file with a date code or a number that counts each build. or even better use hg or git and have the makefile pull the build rev or hash, then you can go back to any specific version and know what the sources were for the code found on the device.  manually modified strings result in many versions with the same string unless you get religious about manually changing it every build, that problem was solved a long long time ago with svn/hg/git type tools

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just put an unused variable in your program:

```c
#pragma RETAIN(version)
static const char version[] = "v1.23 (with yesterday's changes)";
```

and look at it with the debugger.

You might also add `__DATE__` and `__TIME__`.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but i dont know what "#pragma RETAIN(version)" does. I searched web but couldnt find any info. Can you guide me please?

Comment: It retains unused variables.

Comment: This won't work if the chip is locked in production - better to have the code explicitly output the information.

Comment: @ChrisStratton This question is about versioning during development.

Comment: Not necessarily - and just because code has shipped doesn't mean one stops caring to know what version it is.  More likely the opposite!  Hopefully you try locking your chips at some point in development, too, in order to find any issues related to doing so.  And locked or not, it is nice to be able to determine software version via an operational interface, rather than by having to connect a debugger.

Comment: @ChrisStratton, I think I agree, but what exactly do you mean by "locking" here?

Comment: The various device-specific e-fuse bits or special flash locations, which disable readback and/or debug interfaces entirely, which are typically activated in shippable versions of products.  Once that is done, usually the only way to interact over a programming/debug interface is to first command full erasure of the chip, destroying any information contained therein and then resetting the lock bits.